# aviary (adobe creative SDK) doesn't work properly with angular 2

Tags: angular, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I've created simple app with angular 2:
http://plnkr.co/edit/OfjI0jCaZF5kHE45V4ur?p=preview

```
...
declare var Aviary: any;
...
this.featherEditor=new Aviary.Feather({
...
```

This working fine. **But photos always flip vertically in editor** when it appear. What I have to do?

Comment: It is not only with angular 2... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434644/aviary-editor-always-flip-image

Comment: Mine aren't flipping. What size are your photos originally? When does it flip them, after crop or before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following property to your `Aviary.Feather()` configuration object:

```
var editor = new Aviary.Feather({
    // ...
    disableWebGL: true
});
```

The flipping may be due to an outstanding issue related to Web GL support on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ng2-photo-editor fully customizable angular2 photo editor which you can integrate into your HTML5 app within minutes.

1. npm install --save  ng2-photo-editor
2. import { PhotoEditorComponent }     from 'ng2-photo-editor';